# GetStoreConfig returns empty

Tags: magento

In Magento, the function `getStoreConfig($path)` will get the value of $path in table `core_config_data`. I've checked there is a value for the `$path` I use which is `carriers/flatrate/infotext` , but I still got nothing returned from the call `Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate2/infotext')` .

I've tried to disable the cache as well as flushing all caches but it still doesn't work.

This happened when I try to install GLS extension for Magento, is there any case that somehow it interferes with this function ? Thanks

*Update:*

I've just found out something : this function actually returns the text, I find nothing wrong with it but it doesn't work, when I try to use `Magento::getStoreConfig` directly, it works.

```
protected function getInfoText($carrierCode)
{
  if ($text = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/infotext')) {
    return $text;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Magento version: 1.7 CE

Comment: What is GLS extension? Is this extension, that can be installed from Magento Connect? If yes, please provide us a link from where we can download it.

Comment: @ceckoslab it is not freeware or opensource so I cannot provide you a download link. http://tricstore.com/en/magento-extensions.html

Comment: 'carriers/flatrate/infotext' and 'carriers/flatrate2/textinfo' are actually quite different paths. Are you sure you don't want to change function call to Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/infotext')?

Comment: @AlexeiYerofeyev sorry, it's my typo error.

Comment: @all, i've updated my question with something I've just found.

Comment: do a var_dump of
`$text = Mage::getStoreConfig(...); `
when inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento caches the StoreConfig in memory, so make sure you flush all the cache after making change in config_store_data in Magento. This happens when you try to upgrade or install new extension - which is my case.